# Moving files based on name to the corresponding folder

Tags: c#

Hello everyone and well met!  I have tried a lot of different methods/programs to try and solve my problem.  I'm a novice programmer and have taken a Visual Basic Class and Visual C# class.

I'm working with this in C#

I started off by making a very basic move file program and it worked fine for one file but as I mentioned I will be needing to move a ton of files based on name

What I am trying to do is move .pst (for example dave.pst) files from my exchange server based on username onto a backup server in the users folder (folder = dave) that has the same name as the .pst file

The ideal program would be:
Get files from the folder with the .pst extension
Move files to appropriate folder that has the same name in front of the .pst file extension

Update:

```
// String pstFileFolder = @"C:\test\";
// var searchPattern = "*.pst";
// var extension = ".pst";
//var serverFolder = @"C:\test3\";
// String filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pstFileFolder);
// Searches the directory for *.pst

DirectoryInfo sourceDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\test\");
String strTargetDirectory = (@"C:\test3\");
Console.WriteLine(sourceDirectory);
Console.ReadKey(true);>foreach (FileInfo file in sourceDirectory.GetFiles()) {
    Console.WriteLine(file);
    Console.ReadKey(true);

    // Try to create the directory.
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(strTargetDirectory);
    file.MoveTo(strTargetDirectory + "\\" + file.Name);
}
```

This is just a simple copy procedure.  I'm completely aware.  The

> Console.WriteLine(file);
>   Console.ReadKey(true);

Are for verification purpose right now to make sure I'm getting the proper files and I am.  Now I just need to find the folder based on the name of the .pst file(the folder for the users are already created), make a folder(say 0304 for the year), then copy that .pst based on the name.

Thanks a ton for your help guys. @yuck, thanks for the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a pretty trivial application - but what have you tried? Can you post any code so far?

Comment: What code did you use to move the one file.  Could you post an example?

Comment: string psts = "psts";
        DirectoryInfo test2 = new DirectoryInfo(psts);

        if(test2.Exists ==false )
          Directory.CreateDirectory(psts);
        else
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry");
    
        List<String> PSTS = Directory.GetFiles("C:\test", "*.*",     SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

        foreach(string file in PSTS)
        {
            FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
            if(new FileInfo(test3 +"\\"+ mFile.Name).Exists==false)//to remove name collusion
                 mFile.MoveTo(test3 +"\\"+ mFile.Name);

Comment: @Laster: Don't post that much code in comments. Instead, edit your question to include this code.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `File` and `Directory` classes in the `System.IO` namespace. You could use the [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) method to get the names of the files you need to transfer.

Comment: I was just typing a virtually identical answer... do what he said!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a console application to get you started. Note that there isn't **any** error checking and it makes some assumptions about how the files are named (e.g. that they end with `.pst` and don't contain that elsewhere in the name):

```
private static void Main() {
    var pstFileFolder = @"C:\TEMP\PST_Files\";
    var searchPattern = "*.pst";
    var extension = ".pst";
    var serverFolder = @"\\SERVER\PST_Backup\";

    // Searches the directory for *.pst
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(pstFileFolder, searchPattern)) {
        // Exposes file information like Name
        var theFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        // Gets the user name based on file name
        // e.g. DaveSmith.pst would become DaveSmith
        var userName = theFileInfo.Name.Replace(extension, "");
        // Sets up the destination location
        // e.g. \\SERVER\PST_Backup\DaveSmith\DaveSmith.pst
        var destination = serverFolder + userName + @"\" + theFileInfo.Name;

        File.Move(file, destination);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer `DirectoryInfo` because it is more object-oriented.

```
DirectoryInfo sourceDirectory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\MySourceDirectoryPath");
String strTargetDirectory = "C:\MyTargetDirectoryPath";

foreach (FileInfo file in sourceDirectory.GetFiles())
{
    file.MoveTo(strTargetDirectory + "\\" + file.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.IO` is your friend in this case ;)

First, Determine file name by:

```
String filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(SOME_PATH)
```

To make path to new folder, use `Path.Combine`:

```
String targetDir = Path.Combine(SOME_ROOT_DIR,filename);
```

Next, create folder with name based on given fileName

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDir);
```

Ah! You need to have name of file, but with extension this time. `Path.GetFileName`:

```
String fileNameWithExtension = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(SOME_PATH);
```

And you can move file (by `File.Move`) to it:

```
System.IO.File.Move(SOME_PATH,Path.Combine(targetDir,fileNameWithExtension)
```

[Laster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9097965/1009414) already show you how to get file list in folder.